# Use the definition of derivative for $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}, \;x\ne 0\\0, \; x=0\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}, \;x\ne 0\\0, \; x=0\end{cases}$

The best I can do so far is getting it into the following form:

$\lim \limits_{x \to c}\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-c^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)}{x-c}$

But I'm at a loss for what I do next.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I'm sorry but I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this form instead $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} $$

It'll be easier.  Remember, $f(0)$ was defined to be $0$.

Comment: OK so I end up with $\lim x \to 0,\; x\sin(1/x) = 0$

Comment: @the_new_guy Yes, and by definition, that is $f'(0)$.  What more are you looking for?